# Android WebView Rendering Finished

Tags: java, android, webview, rendering

I'm approching with the android development and webviews. 
I want to display the webview just after the rendering has finished, so I got an ImageView visible on the top of the webview. How can i hide the ImageView ONLY after the webview has been rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable javascript in your webview and then pass a javascript interface to webview so that you can interact with android code form javascript.

While setting up the webview add these to enable javascript and javascript interface

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this),
                   "Android");

public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Hide image view */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void hideImageView() {
        imageView.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
     }  
    }
```

In javascript call

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   setTimeout(function () 
 { Android.hideImageView(); }, 3000);
}, false);
```

Note: you need to have this javascript code in your content which you are loading in webview

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't though about this. I'm going to try it but it shoud work fine.

Comment: Sorry this does not solve the problem.. I need something that tell me when the webview has finished to be drawn.

Comment: just try with the new javascript code in the above answer

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // Page is loaded!
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the first method I tried, but the page loaded it's called when contents are loaded in the webview and not when they have been rendered